# Can a TitaniumSDK based mobile application for android use the native widgets of android 4

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

I'm developing a mobile application using the Titanium SDK and did all my UI tests on my own Android2.2 based phone. Beside the huge apk size for a small UI, the application seems to look pretty **native**. I then wanted to see what it would look like on a Android 4 based phone (using the emulator), and was surprised to see that the UIhe didn't really look like a native Android4 app.

I moved from **Phonegap** to **Titanium** especially for native widgets, and expected the framework to use the widgets and them of the version installed on the device where the application is deployed.

Am I missing something? The Titanium SDK seems to target the ***API level 8*** (I suppose given that it's a requirement when setting up the environement for Android development). Or is this more an Android question, enforcing applications targeted at ***API level X*** to look like ***API level X*** application?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal android development the targeted API level is the one responsible for making the UI look native on each API level.

if you can change the API level in titanium, I think the UI will change to what you want.